# If: $A\setminus B=A\cap C$ So: $B\cap C=\emptyset $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Hi I'm trying to prove the following claim, even though **I know it is not true**, I "can" prove ...

If: $$A\setminus B=A\cap C$$ So: $$B\cap C=\emptyset  $$

I suppose the negative:
$$B\cap C\neq \emptyset  $$
So:
$$x\in B,\quad x\in C$$
$$x\in B \Rightarrow x\notin A\setminus B$$
$$x\in C \Rightarrow x\in A\cap C$$
Contradiction?

Where am I lying here?
Thank You!

Comment: What you are trying to prove is simply not true. For a counterexample, put $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$ and $C=\{1,3\}$. Then $A\setminus B=\{1\}=A\cap C$, but $B\cap C=\{3\}\neq \emptyset$. In your reasoning, the last line is not logic. In principle, $x\in C$, but there is no reason to believe that $x$ belong to a $A\cap C$ (which a priori is a smaller set)

Comment: What you are proving is that $A\setminus B=A\cap C$ implies $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for deducing, from $x\in C$, that $x\in A\cap C$, as you do in the last line. Your hypothesis about $x$ is $x\in B\cap C$.